# Can I filter a Google Analytics segment based on content grouping pageview count?

Tags: google-analytics

I want to create a Google Analytics segment for our users who view at least a certain number of pages on our site. From what I can tell (please correct me if I'm wrong) this is easy to do if you don't care about what kind of page they view: you create a filter for the segment that checks to see if `Unique Pageviews` is greater than some value such as `4`. However our site has a whole bunch of pages that I don't really care if someone reads (our "about page" for example). So what I'm trying to do is create a segment of how many people view at least X pages of what we call "Learning Content" (basically two specific page types on our site). How can I segment the users who read a certain amount of learning content?

Two types of pages fit into our definition of `learning content`. The first one has a URL matching a regex that sort of looks like `/learning_content_1/.*` and the second matches regex `/learning_content_2/.*`. I've already created a content group for learning content that correctly identifies these two content groups. However I wasn't able to find any way to filter a segment based on how many unique pageviews (or even just pageviews) come from a *specific* content grouping. Is this even possible? If not, how might I work around that?

**The research I've done so far:** [Google Analytics: How to segment by many groups of pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22050529/google-analytics-how-to-segment-by-many-groups-of-pages?s=1|1.5847) was somewhat helpful but didn't address the question of how to create an actual GA segment based on pageview information for a content grouping or content group.

Answer (score 2):

The only way I can think of handling this, is by associating a specific [custom event](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide?hl=en) that gets triggered on this page. Then you can create a segment that matches users who have **that event category**:
[image]
 *and* **total events greater than 4**:
[image]

It's a workaround, and it doesn't work if you are tracking other events, but maybe that works for you?

Comment: Clever. What do you mean by "doesn't work if you are taking other events"? Can you only track one event per page?

Comment: No, just that the total events count includes _all_ events, so filtering for > 4 will only work if you're only counting one event type!

Comment: Ah. That might be an issue. We definitely track other events. So there's no way to filter on the number of a particular event... Can we create an event that is triggered when another event count reaches X? Event "inception", if you will?